# Need a Https endpoint for microsoft teams and python integration

Tags: python, https, microsoft-teams

I have some python scripts which perform some jobs based on the user inputs I want to host this on microsoft teams. For an outgoing webhook teams asks for a https link where and how do I get it. I am pretty new to this so do not take anything for granted.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this "outgoing webhook" means that Teams has the ability to call a web service of some sort, hosted on a publicly-accessible https address. In the end, it functions very similarly to a bot, so it's possible to just create a full-blown bot. Here's guidance on creating a Microsoft bot (for Teams or otherwise) [using Python](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python).

However, there's a more simple option, of basically just hosting a web function somewhere (e.g. an Azure Function or, I guess, an Amazon Lamba). See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook). As mentioned in this link:

> Outgoing webhooks post data from Teams to any chosen service capable
>   of accepting a JSON payload. Once an outgoing webhook is added to a
>   team, **it acts like bot**, listening in channels for messages using
>   @mention, sending notifications to external web services, and
>   responding with rich messages that can include cards and images.

An Azure Function automatically gets a full, unique, https address, so it's fine to use.

As another example, [this blog post](http://www.wictorwilen.se/creating-a-bot-for-microsoft-teams-using-microsoft-flow) describes how to create a Flow ("Power Automate") that the webhook calls into. This example also ends up using an Azure Function to "glue together" Teams + Flow, but it explains the concepts a bit. You could ignore Flow and just use an Azure Function.

Whether to build an -actual- bot depends on -what else- you might want to be able to do. For instance, do you want to have a more complete conversation with the user? Do you want to the user to be able to interact with your code outside of a channel (e.g. a 1-1 conversation)? These are the kinds of things that will indicate if you might need a proper bot.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use bot framework to create bot that will handle that:
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples

Comment: Is it necessary to have a bot framework? I want to get it done by POST and GET using webhooks.

Comment: In Microsoft teams get the App Studio and setup your application with a bot pointing to your endpoint. Bot needs to be registered - it will allow secure communication between Teams and your API. From your API you can try to handle calls yourself - but the SDK have everything that you need - and it doesn't mean you have to host it on Azure or something.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create a complete end-to-end Bot, which can be a lot of work, - it depends on the scenario