# How do I do Webhook from MS teams to Slack?

Tags: webhooks, slack, microsoft-teams, confluence

How are you?

I use MS Teams at my company.

Send Webhook to MS Teams from Confluence,

After I would like to send the webhook from Teams to Slack.

I think we need to use a bot in Teams or a flow connector.

How do you develop it using what?

To use bot, you need to use Azure subscription, but it seems like a paid license.

Can't you implement the above method for free?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to create an "outgoing" webhook in this manner, and you're right that a bot is the most commonly recommended approach, but here are some points:

1. It's not strictly required to implement a full, complete bot - the endpoint just needs to answer as if it was a bot. I explain that more in this post: [Need a Https endpoint for microsoft teams and python integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296660/need-a-https-endpoint-for-microsoft-teams-and-python-integration)
2. If you *do* decide to create a bot, it's important to know that there are **two kinds** of bots in Azure: (1) a "web app bot", which includes a bot *registration* as well as *hosting* in Azure, or (2) just a *registration* in Azure, with the bot itself hosted somewhere else. See [Register a bot with Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). Azure is just the easiest for hosting, but the standard options are not the cheapest. Incidentally, it is possible to host your bot in an Azure Function, which is MUCH cheaper, but it's a bit of work to get it running.

If you're just wanting the basic webhook option though, I'd suggest the first option (1) above. It also requires an Azure Function, but you might even be  able to function on the free tier, depending on your traffic.

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But we need to provide that function for many other teams, not just for our team.
For Slack, after you create a bot in each workspace,
I can provide various functions using the Bot Token and Slack API.
What should I do with MS teams? @Hilton Giesenow

Comment: This could definitely be used in other teams as well, but I'm not sure what you mean about "provide various functions using the Bot Token and Slack API" - can you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/real_time_messaging.html

Slack creates a bot, which creates a token for the bot.
I'm going to create a Python script, and I'm going to change the bot token into a different environment variable.
You can make it work in each workspace.
I am currently creating several docker containers and providing the bot by the above method. @Hilton Giesenow

Comment: @김동원- Could you please take a look at [Outgoing webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook#code-samples) samples. Even for Outgoing webhook you get [HMAC token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook#2-create-a-method-to-verify-the-outgoing-webhook-hmac-token) which can be used to authenticate the request.

Comment: @Wajeed - MSFT  Thank you for your reply.  If I use the outgoing webbook, do I have to do "@mention" to work? I want to automatically send webhook to slack when webhook comes into Teams, but the above function seems to work if I do "@mention" manually.

Comment: Outgoing webhook work only when you @mention. I believe [change notifications for Microsoft Teams messages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/blogs/announcing-change-notifications-for-microsoft-teams-messages/) might help here. Please let me know.